# Remove a element from an array and assign to a variable

Tags: php, arrays

I  have this array:

```
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
$cars_without_volvo=unset($cars[0]);

print_r($cars);
print_r($cars_without_volvo);die;
```

I need both the `$cars` and `$cars_without_volvo` to later use. The above doesnot seem to work.

Comment: `unset` doesn't return anything. You're probably looking for `array_shift`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy the array to `$cars_without_volvo` and unset from that, then you'd have two different arrays. `unset()` doesn't return anything, it's used to unset elements or variables directly.

This of course assumes that `Volvo` is *always* the first element in the `$cars` array, because we unset the first element.

```
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
$cars_without_volvo = $cars;
unset($cars_without_volvo[0]);

print_r($cars);
print_r($cars_without_volvo);
```

Outputs

```
Array (
    [0] => Volvo
    [1] => BMW
    [2] => Toyota
)
Array (
    [1] => BMW
    [2] => Toyota
)
```

You can also find the key for the `Volvo` element dynamically, by using `array_search()` ([demo](https://3v4l.org/vTiJ1)), by replacing the `unset()` line above with the one below.

```
unset($cars_without_volvo[array_search("Volvo", $cars_without_volvo)]);
```

---

Using `array_shift()` as shown in the other answer is most likely the better approach - *if* the element you wish to remove is the first one. If you want to remove elements in a difference index than the first or last, using this approach might be easier.

- [PHP.net on `unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)
- [Live demo](https://3v4l.org/OZFmt)

Answer (score 3):

`array_shift()` removes the first element from an array, `array_pop` removes it from the end:

```
<?php

$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
$volvos = array_shift($cars);

var_dump($cars, $volvos);
```

Output:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "BMW" [1]=> string(6) "Toyota" } string(5) "Volvo"
```

Check it out here: https://3v4l.org/nZqul
Docs here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php

Comment: This is a better approach than copying the array and then unsetting the first element, that my answer (based on OPs code) is using.